# BibDesk and Jstor

Tags: bibdesk

I have BibDesk (on iMac) and a Jstor subscription. Is there a way to add my Jstor account on BibDesk to automatically download the PDF of my Bibdesk items? That is, is there a way to turn Bibdesk into a PDF storage manager?

Comment: Yes, one of the primary uses of BibDesk is PDF storage management. File downloading typically has to be scripted by the user using AppleScript. There are [old JSTOR download scripts on the wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/wiki/BibDesk_Applescripts/). You may need to investigate whether authentication info can be included in a JSTOR download URL. You could ask for help on the [bibdesk-users](https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/mailman/bibdesk-users/) listserv if nobody responds here.